# Check json sent by retrofit

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I want to check the raw json that is sent by retrofit in my enqueue call. Here goes the code of my click event:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<Product> products = ((MenuAdapter)rvMenuProducts.getAdapter()).getOrderItens();
                ArrayList<Item> orderItemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
                for(Product p: products){
                    orderItemList.add(new Item(p));
                }
                EditText etCardNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_card_number);
                String cardNumber = etCardNumber.getText().toString();

                if(GenericUtils.stringIsNotNullAndNotEmpty(cardNumber)){
                    NewOrder newOrder = new NewOrder(waiterId, establishmentId, cardNumber, orderItemList);

                    WaiterRequester.addOrder(newOrder, new Callback<AddOrderResultInfo>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<AddOrderResultInfo> call, Response<AddOrderResultInfo> response) {
                            int a = 5;

                            Toast.makeText(context, "Pedido realizado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<AddOrderResultInfo> call, Throwable t) {
                            int b = 5;

                            Toast.makeText(context, "VISH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    etCardNumber.setError("ERROOOOOOO");
                }
            }
```

That's it how i call my API, And I'm getting some exception on my api, that I don't know, because my return is a boolean, however when i sent the request using postman, it works!

Here is the json sent by postman:

```
{   
    "newOrder": 
    {
        "idWaiter" : 1,
        "idEstablishment": 6,
        "cardNumber": "123",
        "listItem": [{ "idProduct": 1, "quantity": 1 }]
    }
}
```

And Where is my class NewOrder:

```
public class NewOrder {

    public int idWaiter;
    public long idEstablishment;
    public String cardNumber;
    public ArrayList<Item> listItem;

    public NewOrder() {
    }

    public NewOrder(int idWaiter, long idEstablishment, String cardNumber, ArrayList<Item> listItem) {
        this.idWaiter = idWaiter;
        this.idEstablishment = idEstablishment;
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }

    public int getIdWaiter() {
        return idWaiter;
    }

    public void setIdWaiter(int idWaiter) {
        this.idWaiter = idWaiter;
    }

    public long getIdEstablishment() {
        return idEstablishment;
    }

    public void setIdEstablishment(long idEstablishment) {
        this.idEstablishment = idEstablishment;
    }

    public String getCardNumber() {
        return cardNumber;
    }

    public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getListItem() {
        return listItem;
    }

    public void setListItem(ArrayList<Item> listItem) {
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }
}
```

and Item:

```
public class Item {

    public long idProduct;
    public int quantity;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(Product p) {
        this.setQuantity(p.getQuantity());
        this.setIdProduct(p.getIdProduct());
    }

    public Item(int idProduct, int quantity) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public long getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(long idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

It may be useful, By Object is arriving as a null on backend.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're using Retrofit 2 and thus, you could make an interceptor to log all your requests.

Add `'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'` to your dependency and build your `OkHttpClient` like this:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
```

Finally, add your `OkHttpClient` to your `Retrofit` object:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: If you use the above code, the logs are automatically printed in your logcat

Comment: Didn't printed here :/

Comment: Edited. Should be fixed now in case someone comes across this now.